# How does Fiber handle concurrent requests?

Tags: go, concurrency, request, go-fiber

I was wondering if Go would allocate a new goroutine per each request, like Java does with threads, or does it use an event-queue in the backend to perform tasks asynchronously, like node js (express)?

Go Fiber is one of the fastest frameworks out there and my doubt can be put out simply as **what does fiber framework in go do when there are multiple concurrent requests?**

Comment: I don't know first-hand, but I would be shocked if it's not using one goroutine per request, as the standard library does for network requests.

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual goal what this question is, i.e. what do you want to do with the answer. But trying to find similarities at this level might be the wrong approach. goroutines are implemented internally using events (which are then handled by a few OS threads to spread load over multiple CPU cores) while Java threads are (usually) implemented as OS threads. Thus goroutines are internally more similar to what nodejs  does and only look from the outside similar to what Java does.

Comment: Fiber is fast because it implement only parts of the HTTP specification, puts a shitload of burden on the user and contains no safeguards. No magic tricks regarding how it handles request. Fiber does it exactly like net/http (well, except above points).